# Connecting an external ADC to Mega 2560

Tags: arduino, adc, atmega

I'm fairly new to all of this as well. So I'm working on this project and I have to connect an external ADC, the TLV571 ([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=tlv571&fileType=pdf)), to an Arduino Mega 2560. I know it's complicated and it isn't the easiest solution but that's what I have to work with.

Unfortunately, I don't even know where to begin. I have been looking at the data sheet for the TLV571 all day and am just clueless.

Can anyone help me or give me advice? Even the smallest piece of advice would be helpful!

Comment: Do you want it to be a memory-mapped device or are you willing to use it the brute-force way?

Comment: The brute-force way would be fine! Right now, I just need the two to communicate with each other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

D[7:0] should be connected to any entire 8-bit port. This will allow you to read the entire conversion result at a time without having to perform wacky bit manipulations.

nCS, nWR, nRD, and nCSTART should be connected to pins in ports A, B, C, D, E, F, or G since those pins need to be individually twiddled and those ports are the only ones that work with SBI/CBI.

You likely want to connect nINT to a INTx pin for interrupt-driven conversion, otherwise any pin should be fine.

CLK should be connected to OCnx if you want to use an external clock (see CLKSEL in CR0).

The rest is just hooking up the references and analog input, and following the timing diagrams in the datasheet.